# Mysql query count zero from join where no record

Tags: php, mysql, sql, transactions

I have some spesific database tabel for shop below:

User table

```
+----------+
|id| name  |
+--+-------+
|1 | Mr. A |
|2 | Mr. B |
|3 | Mr. C |
+--+-------+
```

Category item

```
+--+-------+
|id| name  |
+--+-------+
|1 | Cat 1 |
|2 | Cat 2 |
|3 | Cat 3 |
+--+-------+
```

Item table

```
+---+-------------+--------+-------+
|id | category_id | title  | price |
+---+-------------+--------+-------+
|1  |1            | title 1|10     |
|2  |1            | title 2|5      |
|3  |1            | title 3|20     |
|4  |2            | title 4|10     |
|5  |2            | title 5|15     |
|6  |3            | title 6|30     |
+---+-------------+--------+-------+
```

Transaction table

```
+---+--------+--------+---------+------------+----------+
|id | user_id| item_id|buy_value|buy_at_price| date     |
+---+--------+--------+---------+------------+----------+
|1  |1       | 1      |5        |10          |2018-01-01|
|2  |1       | 3      |2        |20          |2018-01-01|
|3  |1       | 3      |1        |20          |2018-01-01|
|4  |2       | 4      |2        |10          |2018-01-01|
|5  |2       | 5      |2        |15          |2018-01-02|
+---+--------+--------+---------+------------+----------+
```

help me to execute a mysql query that can do a daily sales recap by category. examples of such recaps produce a table like this (if recapitulated on 2018-01-01).

Query result should be:

```
+-------------+--------------+--------------------------+-----------------+
| category_id | category_name| total_category_buy_value |category_income  |
+-------------+--------------+--------------------------+-----------------+
|1            | Cat 1        |8                         |110              |
|2            | Cat 2        |2                         |20               |
|3            | Cat 3        |0                         |0                |
+---+-------------+----------+--------------------------+-----------------+
```

but, my query not showing that **Cat 3**.
here is my query

```
SELECT
    category.id AS category_id,
    category. NAME AS category_name,
    sum(`transaction`.buy_value) AS total_category_buy_value,
    sum(
        `transaction`.buy_value * `transaction`.buy_at_price
    ) AS total_income
FROM
    category
JOIN item ON item.category_id = category.id
JOIN `transaction` ON `transaction`.item_id = item.id
WHERE
    `transaction`.date LIKE '2018-01-01%'
GROUP BY
    category_id
```

please visit http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ce4b1/1/0

thank you

Comment: Where is your attempted query? Have you even tried an attempt?

Comment: Please post a [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/). It will be much easier to help you.

Comment: Hello Sean and @ivan86.... my exiting query here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ce4b1/1/0 .... plese help... thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all the categories whether it has transactions (through items) or don't have any transaction data you can use a `LEFT` join to items and transaction table.

```
SELECT
    c.id AS category_id,
    c.name AS category_name,
    COALESCE(SUM(t.buy_value),0) AS total_category_buy_value,
    COALESCE(SUM(t.buy_value * t.buy_at_price),0) AS total_income
FROM
    category c
LEFT JOIN item i ON i.category_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN `transaction` t ON t.item_id = i.id 
                          AND t.date LIKE '2018-01-01%' 
GROUP BY c.id,c.name
```

In above you can also notice i have moved the date filter in `ON` clause from `WHERE` so not whole transaction table will be joined on the data that matches with this filter will be joined, If you use this clause in `WHERE` it will convert the outer join in an inner join

[**DEMO**](http://rextester.com/LHMYH53149)